# Why does object in array does not have the object methods?

Tags: arrays, ruby, class, object

i am trying to create a model with an array of paket_obj. My question is why are there 2 instead of 1 object of the class "paket_obj" and why does they not have the methods of this class?

I want to do this because i want to store, create, delete and manipulate the objects of paket_obj class in this class.The paket_modul class is also used for testing purpose.

here is the paket_modul class. Nothing happens

```
class Paket_Modul
 #Import von Klassen
 require_relative 'paket_obj'

 attr_reader :arrayofpackages

 def initialize
 @arrayofpackages = []
 @arrayofpackages << addnew_Paket
end


def addnew_Paket
   #Paket wird mit einer ID initalisiert
   newpaket = Paket_Obj.new(@arrayofpackages.last == nil ? 0 : @arrayofpackages.last.id_paket+1)
   #Objekt von Typ Paket_Obj dem Array hinzufügen
   @arrayofpackages << newpaket
end

def defineinformation_Paket(param,constantoption)
   @arrayofpackages[param].AddConstant(constantoption)
end

#Why does object in array does not have the object methods?
a = Paket_Modul.new
for param in a.arrayofpackages
  puts param
end

end
```

The paket_obj class

```
class Paket_Obj
attr_accessor :mobilnumber, :emailadresse, :name_ofcertPerson, :id_paket, :id_vorgang, :firma


def initialize(id_paket, attributes = {})
@mobilnumber = attributes[:mobilnumber]
@name_ofcertPerson = attributes[:name_ofcertPerson]
@emailadresse = attributes[:emailadresse]
@firma = attributes[:firmav]
@id_paket = id_paket
@id_vorgang = attributes[:id_vorgang]
end

def AddConstant(param)
puts case param
       when 0
         @mobilnumber = '015224028625'
         @name_ofcertPerson = 'Emil Klaus'
         @emailadresse= 'email@info.de'
         @firma = 'ERTZ'
         @id_vorgang = 0
       when 1
         @mobilnumber = '015758625623'
         @name_ofcertPerson = 'Dirk Heisenberg'
         @emailadresse= 'MAIL@info.de'
         @firma = 'DFGHD'
         @id_vorgang = 1
     end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved. It was simply an error in the code.

First of all:

```
 def initialize
  @arrayofpackages = []
  #This here is wrong. I wanted to initialize the array with an object but forgot to return an object in the method addnew_Paket
  #What i did was adding the reference of the method into the array
  @arrayofpackages << addnew_Paket
 end
```

to do it right we have to do this:

```
  def initialize
   @array_of_packages = Array.new
  end

  def add_new_paket
   newpaket = PaketObj.new(@array_of_packages.last == nil ? 0 : (@array_of_packages.last.id_paket) + 1)
   @array_of_packages << newpaket
  end
```